# Static mp3 player for website

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

I was creating a website for my YouTube channel since I make music for YouTube and etc.

I was wondering how can I add a mp3 player for my website without it stopping on every page reload.

I want the mp3 player to constantly playing no matter how many pages it goes on.

One way I only think this will work is having it on another server side. But the thing is that 1 person isn't going to want to listen to the same music on the website.

I'm able to just broadcast the song on one page but I want users to listen to my music and browse other pages as well.

Can someone please show me how to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: I posted a JSFiddle on my answer, but incase you didn't see it here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/RMbYD/ 
Basically, the idea is that you will be reloading the content in a div, so your master page is not getting postbacks, just the content in the center. Your Mp3 player will be on your masterpage, so as long as your users are on your website, your music will be uninterrupted, if they hit the refresh button or they navigate away, there isn't much you can do to stop that from ending the music.

Comment: Also remember, it is polite to vote on the answers provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

load your content into a div/iframe and have the mp3 playing on the main page.

You'd be best off to go with a div loaded content, iframes are going out the way of the dinosaur.

```
<----- Main  Page -----> Music Player here
>----- ContentDiv -----< Load content into the div
<----- Main  Page -----> Or Music Player here
```

or with an html mockup, Content being what you load your pages into, Music Player being on the main page and never being reloaded.

```
<head></head>
<body id="mainpage">
<div id="musicplayer"></div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So if i have a iframe within a div it will play on all pages? without stopping and replaying the song when a person go onto another page So pretty much just make a extra webpage that the song runs on and embed it in the iframe there?

Comment: You have your main page load once, the music player is on the main page. When they click Navigation links, it loads it into the Content Div in the center/wherever you layout your content.

Comment: so using the ContentDiv add all those onto everypage and everything show go smoothly? but i want whatever song choosen by a user to be player on everylast page without the song restarting or going to another song

Comment: the ContentDiv is for the actual navigating to pages of your website

Comment: Ok so if I add a slide bar from the top of the page and have that inside of it it will be seen on every page. Im going to go try that out and see if it works. Are you able to make a example on jfiddle or something please. So i can get a better understanding?

Comment: i still don't quite understand. Ive tried doing it and it still dont work

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can do that:

The correct way would be for you to set up all your site content as AJAX calls, so your MP3 player would be at the top and untouched. It requires programming knowledge and some planning to make all the AJAX calls correctly.

The easy way, although i don't recommend because it's not W3C valid, is to put a frame at the top with your mp3 player, so it won't postback with the rest of the page when you navegate.

Comment: Im thinking of how to set this up but dont have no idea how this works. are you able to make an example. that would be nice please. Im just confused on how this will work

Comment: Are you working with any programming language (for example: PHP, ASP.NET), or are you doing only HTML/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The answer the Mike has suggested would be a very SEO unfriendly method, if thats a concern, but the only way I can think of to have the music completely unbroken. If you don't mind the break in music between page loads, then you would need to capture the current play length of the track and then pass that in either a cookie or as a parameter in the url which would require you to montior the user behavior and have a js function bound to all naviagtion links monitoring that.

Comment: That's not actually totally true, you can setup a robots.txt file to help the SEO to understand your website layout, without it needed to crawl it like it normally would. Although I'm assuming that he's more concerned with functionality than with the Search engines getting all of his content pages as links.

Comment: I've never heard of a robots.txt file being used to that effect. Surely you would then need to create a website underneath the main one with correct linking and navigation.I suppose its just semantics though, as you said he is most likely concerned with the site working correctly then getting a high page ranking.